# How to run a script with geth attach?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to get latest blocks data and gets all the transaction IDS inside the block and send that transaction IDS array to an api server. I am using this command in geth console :

```
 eth.filter('latest').watch(function(err, result){console.log(result)})
```

Is there a way in which a script will run 24/7 in geth console(get attach) and run the above command to get latest block data and send the transaction IDS array to an api server? Any ideas/help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Use `--exec` along with geth attach:

```
geth --exec "<code>" attach <target>
```

For more information and examples, including the execution of files (loading them from the specified code), see [Non-interactive use: JSRE script mode](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/javascript-console).

Answer (score 2):

You can directly run the JavaScript script under `node` VM. It will have the same execution context as `geth attach` that is effectively a JavaScript console

Examples (scroll to end):

https://tokenmarket.net/blog/creating-ethereum-smart-contract-transactions-in-client-side-javascript/

Comment: Thanks, I read the above link but i am not able to figure out how to run the above eth.filter command to check for each new block and then use a callback to send data to api , can you please give an example for the same

Comment: link archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20180401231221/https://tokenmarket.net/blog/creating-ethereum-smart-contract-transactions-in-client-side-javascript/